# oracle date format comparison ORA-01858

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01858

I have this query on production, which had no problem till yesterday:

```
 SELECT E.ID       
    FROM EXAM_STUD_ENTERANCE E,
         EXAM_REGISTRATION R
   WHERE     E.EXAM_REG_ID = R.ID
         AND E.USER_NAME ='user'          
         AND E.BLOCK = 1
         AND E.STATUS = 1
      AND TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
                'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') >
            TO_DATE (
                  TO_CHAR (R.EXAM_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
               || ' ' || R.EXAM_START_TIME
              ,
               'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')

   AND TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
                'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') <
            TO_DATE (
                  TO_CHAR (R.EXAM_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
               || ' ' || R.EXAM_END_TIME
              ,
               'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

But now  I receive an error

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was
>   expected

Type of columns EXAM_START_TIME and EXAM_END_TIME are NVARCHAR2(100), and stores data like  '16:40' ; EXAM_DATE is DATE

Comment: Which values are causing the problem?

Comment: As an aside, you can get rid of the `to_date(to_char(sysdate, ...), ...)`s and just use `sysdate` instead. It's pointless converting a date to a string and back to a date, given you're using the full date and time!

Comment: If `EXAM_START_TIME` stores data like `16:40` then why are you trying to parse it to a date using a format specifier of `HH24:MI:SS`? Your data doesn't contain :SS !

Comment: `TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
                'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')` can be simplified to `sysdate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yesterday someone inserted a bad value into one of those time columns

Do a

```
SELECT * FROM EDUMAN_EXAM.EXAM_REGISTRATION 
WHERE 
  NOT( 
    REGEXP_LIKE(EXAM_START_TIME, '^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d$') AND
    REGEXP_LIKE(EXAM_END_TIME, '^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d$')
  )
```

Find the bad data, and remove it

Note: you posted an sql that indicates the time columns store `hh:mm:ss` and you said "it was working" but then you claimed that the time columns don't store seconds. If they do store seconds, then use the query as above. If they don't store seconds, reduce the regex pattern to `\d\d:\d\d`

As a side commentary, you should never have made the decision to store this time data as a string. The DATETIME that holds the EXAM_START_DATE can just as easily hold a time, and if you just want the DATE without the time part, you can `TRUNC(some_datetime)` to remove the time component

Store the data in a column of the proper type, and you won't get this issue, and you wont have to get into this ludicrous `date -> string -> concatenate -> parse` process on thousands of records

Comment: Well, you could also make the seconds in the regex optional. I.e. `'^\d\d:\d\d(:\d\d)?$'`

Comment: That would permit values that are too short for the "working" query that was posted, but I'll accept the suggestion of caret/dollar :)

Comment: You need to include the start and end of string anchors too, otherwise you'll find that '123:45:678' will match. Also, you can do `\d{2}` (or, if the data doesn't have 0 padded numbers, `\d{1,2}`), rather than repeating the same characters.

Comment: i can, but \d{2} is more to type than \d\d and harder to understand; pitching to someone who may never have used regex. even considered using [0-9][0-9] as it's more self documenting.. I could even have gone to the nth of [012][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] but it's specifically trying to find nonnumerics, rather than protect against the foolishness of using a varchar to store a time

Comment: `TRUNC(some_datetime)` does **not** "remove" the time component. It only sets the time component to `00:00:00`

Comment: @CaiusJard Btw, this seems to work: `select to_date('31-12-2018 1:2:3','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual`. Somehow that format accepts it without the leading zero's.

Comment: Heh, surprisingly this also seems to work with that format: `select to_date('31-12-2018 5:6','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i know, but EXAM_START_DATE seems to be a datetime, so I judged the OP to be familiar with the concept of a "datetime with no time component" being midnight on the day in question. I still think it's valid to say "trunc 123.456 to remove the fractional(non-integral) component and leave 123.0" and I'm happy to extend that to datetime, the time being a fractional component of the decimal driver for dates

Comment: @LukStorms now that's a surprise - genuinely thought that would have given rise to "ORA-01840 input value not long enough for date format"

Comment: @LukStorms based on a limited set of tests, oracle seems tolerant of any lack of time components, but cannot tolerate date components being absent. Interesting; my learning day for today. I do still think it's wise to align the regex format and the declared format picture rather than allow a variable data, as it could give rise to "date format picture ends before..." if the query is modified to hh:mm and data exists as hh:mm:ss

Comment: @CaiusJard: I think someone who uses expressions like `TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
                'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')` did not understand how DATE or TIMESTAMP values work in Oracle.

Comment: Fair comment :) (his datetime column should still show midnight in his query tool, and if that's what he thinks a timeless date is, then...)

Comment: Thanks to everyone. @Caius Jard your answer solved this problem.There really was bad data in EXAM_START_TIME column.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @NarminHabibova you will get rid of this problem completely if you would use proper data model, i.e. use `DATE` data type for `EXAM_START_TIME` and `EXAM_END_TIME` (drop `EXAM_DATE`) and use time component properly